# Make rebuilds regardless of whether files are changed

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use `make` to build a project that does not contain any C/C++ files.

I have `python` directory in my project that contains some python code that I what to execute during the build process if anything in `python` has changed.

Here is my `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all python

all: python

python: python/
    python python/code.py
```

However, if I just call `make` two times in a row, it builds everything over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clear and succinct answer to my question is that it is **not possible with `make`** if you don't want to keep the "products" of your build process on the disk. The reasons are as follows:

- The only way to declare targets that are not directories or files is to use some of the special targets (see [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)). As per [.PHONY targets documentation](http://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets), a `.PHONY` target is meant to serve as a "name for a recipe to be executed". Thus, `.PHONY` targets may seem suitable for the purpose.
- However, `.PHONY` targets are always rerun from the scratch, regardless of whether their dependencies have changed.

Instead of being insistent on using `make`, I wrote a simple shell script that invokes git to learn whether the `python` directory has changed and builds accordingly. Importantly, in my case, the build process does not leave any files on the local disk since all the produced files are immediately transferred to a remote.

---

Additional notes to those insistent on using `make`:

- `make` needs a "product" of the build process to be present on the disk. Otherwise, `make` has no mechanism to detect that the build has already been run.
- Do not use `.PHONY` targets. Instead, use your "products" of the build as targets and your source files as dependencies. However, for this to work you first need to have some build process "products" that you want to keep. It may be perfectly reasonable not to keep any "products" but still demanding the build process to run only if it has not been done before.

Answer (score 1):

*"if anything in `python` has changed"* is not 100% unambiguous. If it means that you have a set of python source files in `python` and you want to run the recipe each time one of them changes, as [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) explained very clearly, you cannot use `python` as a prerequisite, this will not work because if an existing file changes, the timestamp of `python` does not. Declaring `python` as phony does not help, it just tells make to always run this recipe. And declaring `python` as the prerequisite of itself does not really make sense because make compares the timestamps of the target and the prerequisites and runs recipes only if some prerequisites are newer than the target.

One option would be to declare all these python source files as prerequisites of a target that would be a real file and which timestamp would correspond to the last time the recipe was run. As you do not tell what the effect of the recipe is, we do not know on which product file we could base this. So, let's create an empty file just for this (replace it by a real product file if you have some):

```
PYDIR := python
PYSRC := $(wildcard $(PYDIR)/*.py)

.PHONY: all
all: .python.done

.python.done: $(PYSRC)
    python $(PYDIR)/code.py
    touch $@
```

Of course, if you have sub-directories in `python`, or if your python source files have other extensions than `.py`, or there are other files than python source files that should trigger the re-build, or if some source files can be created with old timestamps, or if some source files can be deleted or any other more complicated case, this simple proposal will not suffice.

For instance if files can be created or deleted in `python` (but not in sub-directories of it), and you want to run the recipe when this happens, you can indeed declare `python` as a prerequisite of `.python.done` because its timestamp changes exactly when this happens:

```
.python.done: $(PYSRC) $(PYDIR)
```

And if you have sub-directories in `python`, you will have to replace `wildcard` by something like:

```
PYSRC := $(shell find $(PYDIR) -type f -name '*.py')
```

And if any file under `python` shall be considered:

```
PYSRC := $(shell find $(PYDIR) -type f)
```

Comment: "_OK. So, the main issue seems to be that make is the wrong tool for what I need to do_" Many developers I know, when they discovered make for the first time, said that it was just a complicated way to achieve what they would do much more elegantly with a script. Some of them changed their mind and are still developers. By the way, what will you compare the last modification time of your python sources with?

Comment: Check whether the python source has changed _compared to what_?  This has never been explained.  Even a shell script will have to compare the timestamps on the files to **something**, to decide if they've been changed.  If that thing is some other file, then make can do the same thing.  If that thing is something that's not a file, then make can't help (except by creating a file to represent that thing).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you expected to happen, but you've declared the target `python` to be a phony target and the make manual clearly states that phony targets are *always* considered out of date and always rebuilt:

> The prerequisites of the special target .PHONY are considered to be phony targets. When it is time to consider such a target, make will run its recipe unconditionally, regardless of whether a file with that name exists or what its last-modification time is.

So, obviously when you run your makefile, the recipe for the phony target `python` will always be run.

Further, if you remove the phony setting this rule will NEVER be run, because you're saying that a directory `python` depends on itself.  It can never be the case that a file is out of date with respect to itself.

I should also point out, listing a directory as a prerequisite is not a magical shorthand that means "check every file in this directory".  It literally means, check the timestamp of the directory.  The timestamp of a directory is only updated when a file in that directory is renamed, removed, or created.  It is not updated when a file in that directory is modified.

Comment: A recipe is the shell script commands that are part of a rule.  A rule consists of a target (the thing on the left of the `:`), a set of prerequisites to build that target (the things on the right of the `:`), and a recipe to build the target (the line(s) indented with TAB that come after the target/prerequisite line).  A target can either be phony, or not phony.  Each target name must be unique.  A target can either represent a file on the disk or not.  But the same target name cannot BOTH represent a file on the disk and not at the same time.

Comment: You should probably read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefiles.html

Comment: Targets can, of course, also be listed as prerequisites of other targets.  If you list a target as a prerequisite of the `.PHONY` special target then it's phony: `.PHONY: python` now the `python` target is phony.  If you don't list it as a prerequisite of `.PHONY`, then it's not phony.

Comment: The question was why invoking make multiple times ran the same rule again, and that's exactly the question I answered, so it doesn't appear that the explanation was obvious when the question was asked.  Sorry if you felt that the answer used a derogatory tone, but I stand my explanation.

Comment: Your question: "make rebuilds regardless of whether files are changed".  My answer: you have declared the target PHONY and the PHONY targets are always rebuilt.  I do agree that the answer is obvious from the documentation, but nevertheless it IS the answer to the question that was asked.  It appears from further discussion you really had a different question, such as how to use Git status to detect whether files are out of date.  But that's not what you asked.  Anyway, I don't think this conversation is productive.  Hopefully you managed to solve your problem.